# Random sigkills when launching application

Tags: ios, crash, sigkill

One time over 10, I have a sigkill when launching my applications from the simulator.
I have absolutely no idea of what could be wrong since I don't do anything to close the application.
I'm afraid this sigkill could occur outside the simulator.

Here is the stacktrace:

[image: The stacktrace]

Do you have enought information with this to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You usually get more information when these kind of crashes occur. Please update your answer with the syslog also. Have you tried to put either breakpoints or some traces in your code to pinpoint where the error occurs?